# Why does the Windows command line change the command when running from a .bat file?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, batch-file

If I want to run the command

```
md5deep -rb . | find /I ".jpg" | sort > local.md5
```

and I run it from the command prompt, it shows exactly like how I typed, but when I put it in a .bat file and run that, this is what I see:

```
md5deep -rb .   | find /I ".jpg"   | sort  1>local.md5
```

It seems that it inserts tabs before `|` and it turns `>` into a `1>`. Why? First I thought that it's something to do with the encoding, but the file is just a simple ANSI file.

Does it have anything to do with `@@` turning `@` inside .bat files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's nothing to worry about. It's just the way the Windows `CMD` parser outputs the lines when you don't suppress the "trace" output using:

```
@echo off
```

or

```
@commandname
```

I'm not sure what you're referring to regarding `@@` versus `@` (except for possibly the above). I don't know of anything special about `@@`, unless you're confusing it with `%%` versus `%` for variable names.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I was thinking about %% with %. So its nothing to worry about, I can just use the same command as I would on a command line? Thanks!

Comment: +1. Indeed, `cmd` is just clarifying here (especially the `1>` part). The statements are identical.

Answer (score 1):

The 1> refers to how standard out is being redirected within the bat file.

You have two channels, one for standard out (1>), and one for standard error out (2>).  They use either 1> or 2> for processing, and provide two different types of execution feedback.  I have this list for different redirection permutations:

```
command > file      Write standard output of command to file
command 1> file     Write standard output of command to file (same as previous)
command 2> file     Write standard error of command to file (OS/2 and NT)
command > file 2>&1     Write both standard output and standard error of command to file (OS/2 and NT)
command >> file     Append standard output of command to file
command 1>> file    Append standard output of command to file (same as previous)
command 2>> file    Append standard error of command to file (OS/2 and NT)
command >> file 2>&1    Append both standard output and standard error of command to file (OS/2 and NT)
commandA | commandB     Redirect standard output of commandA to standard input of commandB
commandA 2>&1 | commandB    Redirect standard output and standard error of commandA to standard input of commandB (OS/2 and NT)
command < file  command gets standard input from file
command 2>&1    command's standard error is redirected to standard output (OS/2 and NT)
command 1>&2    command's standard output is redirected to standard error (OS/2 and NT)
```

This is from Rob van der Woude's excellent web site on Win32 scripting:   http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php

Rob